# How can I query all products under a category includeing child categories' products using Sequelize

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

folks. I'm developing e-commerce using nodejs and sequelize. I need some help, my question is:
How can I query all products under a category including child categories' products using sequelize?

I'm using sequelizeV5 and also 'sequelize-hierarchy' npm package

So far I have this:

```
async categoryAllProducts(req, res) {
        try {
            let category_id = req.params.id;
            let categories = await models.Category.findAll({
                where: sequelize.literal(`id=${category_id} OR parent_id = ${category_id}`)
            });

            await Promise.all(categories.map(async (category)=> {
                let items = await category.getProducts({
                    offset: req.query.offset || 0,
                    limit: req.query.limit || 10,
                    where: req.query.filter ? sqs.find(req.query.filter) : {},
                    order: req.query.sort ? sqs.sort(req.query.sort) : [['id', 'asc']]
                });
                category.dataValues.products = items;
            }));

            return ReS(res, {data: categories}, 200);
        } catch (error) {
            return ReE(res, error, 400);
        }
    },
```

But on that, I can't use limit and offset as I wanted, and there are duplications of the same products in the different child categories. Also, it is not so efficient. Any recommendations?

Comment: database demo image is here: https://i.ibb.co/GthQXx9/demo.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I understand your problem. I think you should do it similar to this.

```
async categoryAllProducts(req, res) {
    try {
        let category_id = req.params.id;

        const products = await models.Product.findAll({
           include: [{
              model: models.Category,
              // you should use sequelize.Op
              where: sequelize.literal(`id=${category_id} OR parent_id = ${category_id}`)
           }],
           offset: req.query.offset || 0,
           limit: req.query.limit || 10,
           order: req.query.sort ? sqs.sort(req.query.sort) : [['id', 'asc']]
        })

        return ReS(res, {data: products}, 200);
    } catch (error) {
        return ReE(res, error, 400);
    }
},
```